# ionic/cordova vs react native in 2020

Tags: react-native, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm sure that such a question already asked, but important thing that now mobile phones more powerful than 5-6 years ago. I just remember how hybrid mobile apps was slow especially with animations, transitions between screens, delay on touch. Today in our company we developing mobile app with ionic (twitter-like app for organization internals) and it works really smooth and fast. I've also developed the same app with same screens on react native and actually don't feel difference.
I understand that by definition react native should perform better because it's "more native". But is it still exists significant reason to write app in react native or ionic/cordova is completely enough to feel "native" in application?
I prefer to write code with react, but ionic now supports react as well.

Comment: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) You need to ask a specific programming question that can return a specific answer and that isn't asking for opinion.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very great question.

Firstly, the "mainstream" advantages for React Native over Ionic is:

- Performance [60 fps on animations];
- Native look n feel;
- Smooth Native Navigation;
- Native modules

And Ionic over React Native:

- PWA in mind;
- Share full web codebase;
- One team for two platforms;

But, i understand your doubt.

> "Still exists significant reason to write app in react native or
>   ionic/cordova is completely enough to feel "native" in application?"

If your app need fluid animations or high CPU or GPU usage, you may have issues with Ionic or other webview-based framework.

However, if your app don't need so much processing, Ionic may the best choice here, and so less complex to build.

Comment: I wouldn't consider the look and feel as a reactive native advantage, because Ionic also provides that out of the box, without changing a single line of code from android to iOS (at least in versions 4 and 5 it does). I've built an ionic app that I've submitted to some developers to get some reviews. 100% of them thought it was built with flutter (maybe because I was studying flutter by that time). But the point is that someone will hardly notice, based on look and feel, what technology you've used. And ionic team did an excellent job on styling.

Comment: The "OS-emulated" look is 90% ok, but a bad behavior can results in a bad native feeling. And yes, you can have a bad app using any SDK, even using the native one. When using Ionic 4 sample android app, i can feel some issues that i can't see on RN or Flutter, like: button tap delays; poor parallax rendering while doing a scrolling in header; Android tab-view's performance so distant from native (or even from flutter). However the Ionic project is excellent and the team is doing a nice job!

Comment: Thank you for the response!
Actually we have a little animation there, but transition transform looks smooth. The problem was only when list of items was longer than 30-40 items. But virtual scroll solved the problem. Perhaps in react native 30-40 items in such list not a limit )

Comment: So i think that go ahead with Ionic is the best choice! =)